# Is it possible to generate an xml for an xsd simple type?

Tags: xml, xsd, simpletype

I've got the following simple type coming from a Corba IDL translated to xsd:

```
<xs:simpleType name="fooType" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="bar" />
        <xs:enumeration value="baz" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The problem I'm facing is how to create an xml file matching this xsd? I mean, I barely know how to do for complex types, but this simple type with enumeration puzzles me.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this XSD-fragment only defines a custom simple type, what exactly do you want to know?

The given type defines a string that can either be `bar` or `baz`.

As the definition is only a **type**-definition, you'll have to use some kind of `element`-definition that actually uses the **type**, e.g.:

```
<xs:element name="foo" type="fooType"/>
```

This will allow the following tags in your XML:

```
<foo>bar</foo>
<foo>baz</foo>
```

Comment: OK, and should I add this element definition within the xsd, or the xml, please?

Comment: The `element`-definition has to go into the schema (XSD).

Comment: Well, thanks. I've now to wonder why there isn't such a definition in my generated xsd.

Comment: Perhaps the type is simply used as the base-type for some other type. Sorry but I am not familiar with Corba IDL and its transformation into an XSD schema.